# Get "description" value of JSON Schema on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I was reading MongoDB docs in JSON schema keywords section https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#json-schema

In the example shown here:

```json
$jsonSchema: {
      bsonType: "object",
      required: ["name"],
      properties: {
        name: {
          bsonType: "string",
          description: "this is the name"
        }
      }
    }
```

One of the keywords that can be used is "description". I want to know that it is possible to get the value of the description through an ODM like moongose ​​so that I can display it elsewhere, is there a way to get this value?

Thanks for your help and answers.